# Does given point satisfy FONC?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

minimize $4x_1^2+2x_2^2-4x_1x_2-8x_2$

subject to $x_1+x_2\leq 4$

Does the point $(2,2)$ satisfy the FONC for a local minimizer?

The gradient of the objective function is

$\nabla f = \begin{bmatrix} 8x_1^2-4x_2-4x_2 \\ 4x_2^2-4x_1-8\end{bmatrix}$ = $\begin{bmatrix} 0\\0 \end{bmatrix} $

Filling in the point should give $0$ but it doesn't so the answer is no. Is this correct or do I have to use Lagrange?

Comment: What does FONC mean?

Comment: Now I found this shortcut in a [related post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1374515/find-vector-that-maximizes-fx-2x-122x-22-x-332x-1x-2). So it seems it stands for [first-order necessary condition](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22first-order+necessary+condition%22).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a non-calculus approach to find the minimum.

By completing the square we get
$$
\begin{align}
f(x_1,x_2)&=4x_1^2+2x_2^2-4x_1x_2-8x_2\\
&=4\left(x_1-\frac{x_2}2\right)^2+x_2^2-8x_2\\
&=4\left(x_1-\frac{x_2}2\right)^2+(x_2-4)^2-16\\
&=(2x_1-x_2)^2+(x_2-4)^2-16
\end{align}
$$

After the substitution $y_1=2x_1-x_2$ and $y_2=x_2-4$ we transform
this to the problem to minimize
$$g(y_1,y_2)=y_1^2+y_2^2-16$$
for
$$y_1+3y_2\le -4.$$

This is the same question as finding the point on the line
$y_1+3y_2=-4$, which is closest to the origin. Geometrically we can
see that this point must belong to the perpendicular line $3y_1-y_2=0$
and we get $y_1=-\frac25$, $y_2=-\frac65$ with $g(y_1,y_2)=\frac4{25}+\frac{36}{25}-16=\frac85-16=-\frac{72}5$.

This corresponds to $x_1=\frac65$ and $x_2=\frac{14}5$.

WolframAlpha [yields the same result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimize+4x%5E2%2B2y%5E2-4xy-8y+for+x%2By%3C%3D4).